# Why is vis.js adding an unexpected amount of space between trees?

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

With regards to the code below, I could not figure out why `vis.js` added a lot of space between trees.

```
var options = {
    //locale: 'en',
    interaction:{hover:true, dragNodes :false},

      layout: {
        randomSeed: undefined,
        hierarchical: {
            enabled: true,
            parentCentralization: true,
        }
      },
    edges: {
    color: {
        opacity: 0.4,
    }},
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pavn23/zmttds9q/

Comment: How many spaces were you expecting and how many actually occurred? What are you first thoughts as to why the code is performing unexpectedly?

Comment: With option
     physics: {
     enabled: false,
     },
the tree decreases - better but not enough for me
nodes stretch horizontally

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the physics default.
You can change it to false.
You can also config the treeSpacing like so...

```
         physics: false,
            /*layout: {
                hierarchical: {
                    enabled: true,
                    levelSeparation: 190,
                    nodeSpacing: 250,
                    treeSpacing: 280,
                    sortMethod: "hubsize"
                }
            }*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried the proposed settings earlier, the second level is not clearly stretched. You can try here: https://jsfiddle.net/pavn23/znv5aypk/

Comment: Well, I have tried the options:
**    physics: {
     hierarchicalRepulsion: {
      centralGravity:3,
      springLength: 75,
      springConstant: 0.105,
      nodeDistance: 250
     },
     minVelocity: 0.75,
     solver: "hierarchicalRepulsion"
    }**
and I think it looks OK. But you can play with it, I think.

Comment: Thank you for your option - it looks much better, but not perfect for me. I'll try again, the best option I'll provide.